# Initializing Mobile Hotspot using bluetooth C#

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-10, hotspot

I need to create a service that starts a mobile hotspot using bluetooth. I've found the code to create a hotspot service, but this creates a hotspot with the Ethernet adapter.

I've read the documentation and can't find anything to specify bluetooth like in the settings UI.

[image: Windows setting Mobile Hotspot UI]

This is the code to initialize the hotspot with the Ethernet adapter.

```
var connectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
var tetheringManager = Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager.CreateFromConnectionProfile(connectionProfile);
```

The problem with this is that the network is shared through WiFi, and not Bluetooth.

Here are my current connections:
[image: Current connections]

My OS were unfortiunately installed in Norwegian, but the display should look familiar in English.

Comment: Hi @Simen Nielsen did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`GetConnectionProfiles` returns a `IReadOnlyList` of [`ConnectionProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile). You can then try to select a specific profile from the list to operate on, instead of using the default one you have in your snippet.

Comment: I've tried all possible connection profiles which this function returns, still no luck.